# How to fail parcel/babel/typescript proccess on complication errors/warnings?

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs, parceljs

index.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Home from "./home";

const x:number = "aaa"
const x:number = "aaa"
const x:number = "aaa"

ReactDOM.render(<Home/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

The build should fail due to: multiple identifiers of the same name (js) and invalid type (string to number variable) (ts).

Currently, parcel compiles successfully. How can I enforce a failure in such cases?

---

Minimal working project-example: https://github.com/stavalfi/learning-parcel-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ts-loader` will do the trick.

Example: https://github.com/stavalfi/lerna-starter